# UI to stay horizontally centered on the screen while items are added / removed

Tags: ios, uiview, uistackview

I need a sort of horizontal container to stay horizontally centered on screen while items are added or removed.

I decided to use horizontal UIStackView with 'align horizontally in container'. Once I added an item to it (in design mode), it stopped being centered. Moreover the size on the stack view are well as size of child view are greyed out!

I agree that the stack view size is controlled automatically. But why can't I set up the sizes of child views?

If UIStackView in inappropriate in my case, what should I do?

Comment: Can you show code for how exactly you set your stack view up?

Comment: kind share screen short what you trying to achieve